# Remove unnecessary markup from a dynamically generated UL menu from Json

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working on this menu for the last couple of days, everything works the way planned, but after parsing the json to thea view the generated html has some extra markup that is not needed and this is creating issues when adding styles, at this stage of the project I can not modify the Json structure. I created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/c3urzem6/ and I'am attaching an image of the extra markup: [image: Extra markuo]

This is the javascript function:

```
function list(object) {

            var listView="<ul class='dropdown'>";

            for(prop in object){
            var value = object[prop];

            switch (typeof(value)){
                        case "object":
                        var token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,16);

                        listView += "<li><div id='"+ token +"' class='collapse'>"+list(value)+"</div></li>";
                        // listView += "<li>"+list(value)+"</li>";
                        break;

                        case "number": //Need to confirm if ID will be always a number
                        listView += "<span class='hidden'>"+value+"</span>";
                        break;

                        default:

                        listView += "<li>"+value+"</li>";
                    }
                }

                return listView+"</ul>";


        }
```

Updated image highlighting the extra markup.
[image: updated image]

Comment: Can describe "unnecessary markup" ?

Comment: If you look at the image in the top, all the markup highlighted with red, basically the json should render from  the ul class dropdown > li {Americas} and below. All the extra markup (in red) is making this ul hard t style and add more js.

Comment: Basically the first two "ul.dropdown > li > div" from the top to bottom, this markup is not holding any content at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var filtered = $(list(data)).find(".dropdown:gt(0)")
    .filter(function(i, el) {
      return /Americas|APJ|Asia/.test($(el).find("li").eq(0).text())
    });
    $("#sidebar").html(filtered);    
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c3urzem6/4/

Comment: This is a good solution but is also removing the siblings li's > ul  from the same index level, if you look at the json data from the jsfiddle ""level_0_name": "APJ"," and "level_0_name": "Asia", are gone from the output, thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway to instead of hardcode the values with the filter "return /Americas|APJ|Asia/.test($(el).find("li").eq(0).text())" do something like return **key has value** .test($(el).find("li").eq(0).text()) @guest271314

Comment: @user1547007 Not certain about "key has value" ? "key" of ? "value" of what ? What is issue with approach of `/Americas|APJ|Asia/.test($(el).find("li").eq(0).text())` ?

Comment: Hello @guest271314, just need a way to make this script more flexible, the actual values of the json are changing from time to time and can't always target/filter '/Americas|APJ|Asia/' values.